# I wanted to know on android studio webview if it was possible to disable some links on the page (telegram instagram email)

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

In a nutshell I want that when I click on telegram in webview I don't want the link to open or if I click on telegram I want to stay on the same page without the link opening

i tried to search but i didn't find anything, at most i found something about how to disable all links on the webview and not some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use webview client to intercept the clicks.

### **Code :**

**In your webview set webViewClient**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            if (isValidEmail(url)) {
                return true;
            } else if (url.contains("www.instagram.com"))
                return true;
            else if (url.contains("https://t.me"))
                return true;
            else
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // do nothing
            //super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
    });
```

**To check whether it'a valid email :**

```
  public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {     return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
 }
```

Now in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you can check the url and return whether to override url loading or not according to your need.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252893/discussion-on-answer-by-kamal-nayan-i-wanted-to-know-on-android-studio-webview-i); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
    webView.loadUrl("https://streamingcommunity.love/");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    MyChrome() {}

    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
    {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
    }

    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        if (isValidEmail(url)) {
            return true;
        } else if (url.contains("www.instagram.com")) {
            return true;
        } else if (url.contains("https://t.me"))
                    return true;
        } else {
             return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        // do nothing
        //super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    public boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
    }
});
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252917/discussion-on-answer-by-gege-i-wanted-to-know-on-android-studio-webview-if-it-wa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        if (url.contains("mailto:"))
            return true;
        if (url.contains("www.instagram.com"))
            return true;
        if (url.contains("https://t.me"))
            return true;
        else
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
});
```

Comment: bro I tried to make a change to the code and I can tell you that the same goes for the email that doesn't open everything is ok

Comment: then I wanted to ask you another thing do you know how can I insert an adblocker inside the code, I found something on google but I didn't find much

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).